# Allow Apache to execute command in root?

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, root, visudo

I am setting up a bash/html CGI that will allow me to generate graphs with GnuPlot under RedHat 7.6.
My tutor ask me to create a cgi script that will be able to return a sudo id (root) without a password, only using the " id " command, not " sudo id "

I've just add the id command in my cgi source code in order to display the result of this command on the first page of my cgi :

[image]

Actually, if I add the id command in one of my cgi-script, the return is :

```
uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache) context=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0
```

So I going on the the visudo file and I try to add this at the end of the visudo file :

```
httpd ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: id
```

Or

```
apache ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: id
```

My cgi return this again and again :

```
uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache) context=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0
```

But I want this return :

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

Could you show me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the username as the first parameter to `id` you get the desired output.

```
[user@host ~]# id root
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) Gruppen=0(root)
```